# How can I target AJAX content with this jquery, containing .each?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What would be the best way to execute the code below on content that is loaded via ajax?

```
$(".tabledefault tr td br").each(function(i, el) {
    // if `br` next sibling does not contain alphanumeric characters,
    // hide parent `tr` element
    if (el.nextSibling.nodeType === 3 
            && el.nextSibling.nodeValue.match(/\w+/) === null
            || $(el).next(":empty").length) {
        $(this).closest("tr").hide()
    }
})
```

I tried wrapping it in this to no avail:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.tabledefault tr td br', function(){
    $(".tabledefault tr td br").each(function(i, el) {
    // if `br` next sibling does not contain alphanumeric characters,
    // hide parent `tr` element
    if (el.nextSibling.nodeType === 3 
            && el.nextSibling.nodeValue.match(/\w+/) === null
            || $(el).next(":empty").length) {
        $(this).closest("tr").hide()
    }
});
```

This is the link to the page itself: [page in production](http://crownsportscenter.mattswinehart.com/parties)

The ajax call doesn't happen until the form is submitted.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You're mousing over one element, but then running the code over **all** the elements. Is that really what you want?

Comment: maybe try use span instead of br, but anyway, what's the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you should just run the original code after loading the new content with AJAX. Put it into a named function to make it easy to call it from multiple places.